# sort array of mixed integer and string values

Tags: ruby

Example data:

`["A-1.jpg", "A-2.jpg", "A-10.jpg", "A-101.jpg", "B-1.jpg", "B-2.jpg"]`

I need this sorted so that all A's come first and the numeric value in ascending order, e.g. 'a-2' is before 'a-10' which are both before 'b-1'

Thanks.

Comment: We'd like to see evidence of your effort toward solving this. Did you write code? If not, why? Did you search for a solution? Where did you search and why didn't that help? Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. As is it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = ["A-1.jpg", "A-10.jpg", "A-2.jpg", "A-101.jpg", "B-1.jpg", "B-2.jpg"]
arr.sort_by { |s| first, last = s.split("-"); [first, last.to_i] }

 => ["A-1.jpg", "A-2.jpg", "A-10.jpg", "A-101.jpg", "B-1.jpg", "B-2.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["A-1.jpg", "A-2.jpg", "A-10.jpg", "A-101.jpg", "B-1.jpg", "B-2.jpg"].sort_by{|s| s =~ /^(\w)-(\d+)\.jpg$/ && $1.ord * 1000 + $2.to_i}
```